# PHP get abbreviated timezone based on date and location

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a number of dates times and locations stored as strings in my db. Some of the dates are already formatted the way I want:

`Apr 29, 2017 09:00 EDT`

but many are missing the timezone and I want to do the following with the ones that don't:

1. Using the state location (indiana, ohio, california, new york, etc) found elsewhere in the db for each datetime entry, return the correct abbreviated timezone.
2. Timezone returned should include daylight savings time calc for that date, so for example if my date is `Jun 25 2017 15:00` and my location is New York it should return `EDT` (not `EST`)

Also, do I have to build my own lookup table to translate php timezones like `America/New_York` or are there built in functions to handle this?

When I try to convert some of these using:

`date('M j, Y H:i T', strtotime($mydatetimestring))`

all of them have `UTC` tacked on the end, including the ones that already have a timezone. I need to keep each datetime in its respective timezone stored in the db, not convert them all from/to UTC.

Comment: The reason `date()` always returns UTC is because that's the time zone your server is set to. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php Timestamps, as returned by `strtotime()` and used by `date()`, are integers and only contain a time, not a time zone. As for the rest: I think you have to spend an hour making your lookup table, to find the relation between states and time zones, it's easier than you might think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this took a lot of tweaking and research, but here is the solution, hope it helps someone else. There are several steps to achieve what I wanted:

1. had to get all my datetime strings and make sure they were valid
   using `strtotime`
2. had to get the lat long from google to be able to
3. get the timezone from google
4. had to then convert google's timezone to my abbreviation
5. finally I could update the db with fixed values.

Here is the code:

```
  $fix_time_string = $myqueryresult;

    foreach ($fix_time_string as $fix_time_string_record) {
        $convertone = strtotime($fix_time_string_record->my_datetime_string);
        if ($convertone) { //Check that my datetime string is convertable first
            $address = $fix_time_string_record->my_location_string;
            if ($address !== '') { // Check that I have an address
                $json = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . urlencode($address) . '&key=MY_GEOCODE_API_KEY');
                $obj  = json_decode($json);
                if (!$obj->status[0] == 'ZERO_RESULTS') { //Don't do the following if there is no result from google for the address
                    $lat      = $obj->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
                    $lng      = $obj->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
                    $jsonzone = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=' . $lat . ',' . $lng . '&timestamp=' . $convertone . '&key=MY_TIMEZONE_API_KEY');
                    $objzone  = json_decode($jsonzone);

                    // Set up my conversions from google's timeZoneName
                    if ($objzone->timeZoneName == "Pacific Standard Time") {
                        $tzabbr = "PST";
                    } elseif ($objzone->timeZoneName == "Pacific Daylight Time") {
                        $tzabbr = "PDT";
                    } elseif ($objzone->timeZoneName == "Mountain Standard Time") {
                        $tzabbr = "MST";
                    } elseif ($objzone->timeZoneName == "Mountain Daylight Time") {
                        $tzabbr = "MDT";
                    } elseif ($objzone->timeZoneName == "Central Standard Time") {
                        $tzabbr = "CST";
                    } elseif ($objzone->timeZoneName == "Central Daylight Time") {
                        $tzabbr = "CDT";
                    } elseif ($objzone->timeZoneName == "Eastern Standard Time") {
                        $tzabbr = "EST";
                    } elseif ($objzone->timeZoneName == "Eastern Daylight Time") {
                        $tzabbr = "EDT";
                    }
                    // format and create my new value
                    $newtimevalue = date('M j, Y H:i', strtotime($fix_time_string_record->my_datetime_string)) . " " . $tzabbr;

                    // update my values in the db (wordpress here btw)
                    update_post_meta($fix_time_string_record->ID, 'my_datetime_string', $newtimevalue, $fix_time_string_record->my_datetime_string);                        

                    // echo what I did
                    echo $fix_time_string_record->ID . " changed from " . $fix_time_string_record->my_datetime_string . " to " . $newtimevalue . "<br>"; 

                } else {
                    echo $fix_time_string_record->ID . " can't get lat long from this ID for some reason. <br>";
                }
            } else {
                echo $fix_time_string_record->ID . " has an empty address, can't get timezone without location <br>";
            }
        } else {
            echo $fix_time_string_record->ID . " UNCONVERTABLE datetime string <br>";
        }
        // show output after each iteration
        flush();
        ob_flush();

    }
```